# Count records from multiple tables in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions

I am trying to count different status of a document from a database table.

Assume table one has :

```
select docid, year, type, statusid
from table1
where docid in (1, 2) and year = '2016'
```

This returns:

```
docid year type statusid
------------------------
1     2016  pdf   231
1     2016  pdf   231
1     2016  pdf   231
1     2016  pdf   232
1     2016  pdf   232
1     2016  pdf   235
1     2016  pdf   235
```

but I need to return only one record like

```
docid  year  type   granted  revoked deleted others
----------------------------------------------------
1      2016   pdf    3        2       2        0
```

whereas status are in a different table

Table2

```
statusid     status       masterid
----------------------------------
231          granted      51
232          revoked      51
235          deleted      51
236          others       51
```

What I tried is:

```
select 
    docid, year, type,statusid 
    case 
       when statusid = 231 
          then count(statusid) 
       else 0 
    as granted,
    case 
       when statusid = 232 
          then count(statusid) 
       else 0 as revoked,
    case 
       when statusid = 235 
          then count(statusid) 
       else 0 as deleted,
    case 
       when statusid = 236 
          then count(statusid) 
       else 0 as others
from 
    table1
where 
    docid in (1, 2) and year = '2016'
group by 
    docid, year, type, statusid
```

But this is returning 3 rows whereas output should be only one row with all status count.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close.  The `case` needs to be the argument to the aggregation function and you don't want `statusid` in the `group by`:

```
select docid, year, type,
       sum(case when statusid = 231 then 1 else 0 end) as granted,
       sum(case when statusid = 232 then 1 else 0 end) as revoked,
       sum(case when statusid = 235 then 1 else 0 end) as deleted,
       sum(case when statusid = 236 then 1 else 0 end) as others
from table1
where docid in (1,2) and year='2016'
group by docid, year, type
```

Comment: i tried removing statusid from groupby but then it was not allowing me to use statusid in case and I dont know how sql is allowing the selection of same column in aggregate case. Thank You:)

Answer (score 1):

You can use pivot for the same as below:

```
Select * from (
    Select docid, [year], [type], [status] from table1 d 
    Join table2 dt on d.statusid = dt.statusid
) a
Pivot (count([status]) for [status] in ([granted],[revoked],[deleted],[others])) p
```

Output as below:

```
+-------+------+------+---------+---------+---------+--------+
| docid | year | type | granted | revoked | deleted | others |
+-------+------+------+---------+---------+---------+--------+
|     1 | 2016 | pdf  |       3 |       2 |       2 |      0 |
+-------+------+------+---------+---------+---------+--------+
```